# Stop DIV with overflow:hidden from scrolling when textbox is clipped

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

I have a DIV with, importantly, the css overflow:hidden

```
<div style="width:800px;height:400px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;position:relative;"></div>
```

I append a textbox element inside the DIV with css position:absolute. When I use javascript to place the textbox near the edge of the DIV's boundary, so that some of the textbox will be hidden past the div's boundary, that works fine. But then when I enter text into it and the text goes past the div's boundary, it automatically scrolls the div so the whole textbox can be seen. This is undesired behaviour. Is there anyway to prevent this.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rnj27/

I added a red square inside it, so you could see the DIV was definitely scrolling. Just enter text into the textbook until it goes past the boundary.

Comment: @user3168736 updated with JSfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery `.focus` to achieve this:

```
$("#txtBox").focus(function(){
    $(this).closest("#parentDiv").toggleClass("focused");
});
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnj27/5/). Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I change your `<input>` code into this:

```
<input type="text" size="14" 
style="max-width:100px;height:20px;
border:1px solid black;position:absolute;left:700px;top:200px;"></input>
```

The tricky part is to use `size` and `max-width`, using only `max-width` will give you a little resize glitch. However you can pick the right size so it won't resize.. Hope it helps..